# Elm - performing math operations on a mixture of Signals and numbers

Tags: math, numbers, signals, elm

Given

```
a : Float
```

how would one write the expression

```
Mouse.x - a
```

correctly? The aim is to evaluate an expression like this:

```
(Mouse.x - a) < 2
```

Currently the error given is

```
(-) is expecting the left argument to be a:

    number

But the left argument is:

    Signal Int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mouse.x` is of type `Signal Int`. You'll need to use [`Signal.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Signal#map) to respond to the mouse signals in order to do any math with the value.

```elm
import Mouse
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)

main =
  Signal.map showMouseInfo Mouse.x

showMouseInfo x =
  show <| "Original x: " ++ toString x ++ "; x-1: " ++ toString (x - 1)
```

You can paste that into http://elm-lang.org/try to play around with the concepts.